# macOS - Anyone knows how to scale view in Xcode when programming for macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-storyboard

How can I scale storyboard view when developing MacOS app? When I do iPhone/iPad Developement I can scale the storyboard content either by Clicking on +/- at the bottom of the storyboard pane or by holding down option key and using scrolling wheel on my mouse. None of this is available when I start MacOS projet in Xcode. How come? I could use it even more in MacOS development than in iPhone development since MacOS apps usually occupy more sreen real estate than iPhone apps. Is there anything hidden that needs to be enabled in order to scale storyboard view in Xcode?

Comment: For other users, scaling with iOS apps can be done by using two fingers on the trackpad by moving your fingers closer or further apart

Answer (score 2):

The answer, sadly, is that Xcode simply doesn't support scaling in AppKit storyboards. It only supports scaling in UIKit storyboards.

You should file a feature request at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I can sort of justify how this situation came about historically with an imaginary story about how MacOS acquired storyboards late in the game, the implications of the presence of things like the menu bar, etc. But the OP's feature request would certainly be a good one.

Comment: Considering how long Apple dinked around with variable UI scaling without ever getting it to a really usable state ([started in 10.4](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2005/04/macosx-10-4/20/#scalable-ui) in 2005, [abandoned in 10.7 in favor of 2x scaling only](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7/14/#hi-dpi) in 2011), I'm not surprised Apple hasn't wanted/been able to make it work for AppKit in IB.